# SharpPDF create PDF in Serverside asp .Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, sharppdf

I have samples to create PDF, however for the server side creation of PDF there is no documentation about SharpPDF. I think it is about stream concept, which I have no information about it.

```
pdfDocument myDoc = new pdfDocument("TUTORIAL", "ME");
pdfPage myPage = myDoc.addPage();

myPage.addText("Hello World!", 200, 450, sharpPDF.Enumerators.predefinedFont.csHelvetica, 12);
myDoc.createPDF(@"c:\test.pdf");
myDoc.
myPage = null;
myDoc = null;
```

Comment: I'm sorry @kirlisakal, but what is your question? How to handle this file to the user on a WebForms app?

Comment: How do you mean there is no documentation for the server side? Also, your code is not valid C#. What is happening? Are you getting an error? What error is it?

Comment: yes Andre, I am using webForms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload for [`createPDF`](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/DOC/sharpPDF.pdfDocument.createPDF_overload_1.html) that takes a `Stream`. You can use this to create the PDF in memory on the server and then stream it back to the client.

Here is an example (tried with ShartPDF version 1.3.1):

```
PdfDocument myDoc = new pdfDocument("TUTORIAL", "ME");
pdfPage myPage = myDoc.addPage();
myPage.addText("Hello World!", 200, 450, predefinedFont.csHelvetica, 12);

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
myDoc.createPDF(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Flush();
```